# MVVM RaisePropertyChanged

Tags: .net, silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

I have a custom datagrid in my application that when its source is empty it should display a message saying "No results", and when the source is not empty it should display the source data and no message should be displayed.

My custom datagrid is:

```
namespace GenericControls
{
    [TemplatePart(Name = "EmptyDataGridTextBlock", Type = typeof(TextBlock))]
    public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
    {
        private TextBlock _txtEmptyDataGrid = null;

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEmptyDataGridProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsEmptyDataGrid", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomDataGrid), null);
        public static readonly DependencyProperty EmptyDataGridTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EmptyDataGridText", typeof(string), typeof(CustomDataGrid), null);

        public CustomDataGrid()
        {
            IsEmptyDataGrid = true;
        }

        public bool IsEmptyDataGrid
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)base.GetValue(IsEmptyDataGridProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(IsEmptyDataGridProperty, value);
                if(_txtEmptyDataGrid != null)
                {
                    _txtEmptyDataGrid.Visibility = IsEmptyDataGrid ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
                }                
            }
        }

        public string EmptyDataGridText
        {
            get
            {
                if (_txtEmptyDataGrid != null)
                {
                    return _txtEmptyDataGrid.Text;
                }

                return (string)base.GetValue(EmptyDataGridTextProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                if (_txtEmptyDataGrid != null)
                {
                    _txtEmptyDataGrid.Text = value;
                }
                base.SetValue(EmptyDataGridTextProperty, value);                
            }
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            _txtEmptyDataGrid = GetTemplateChild("EmptyDataGridTextBlock") as TextBlock;
            if (_txtEmptyDataGrid != null)
            {
                _txtEmptyDataGrid.Text = EmptyDataGridText;
                _txtEmptyDataGrid.Visibility = IsEmptyDataGrid ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

My XAML is as follows: my:CustomDataGrid Height="180" Name="dgChildren" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChild, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Childrens}" **IsEmptyDataGrid="{Binding IsEmptyDataGrid}"**>

---

In my ViewModel I have the property IsEmptyDataGrid:

```
public bool IsEmptyDataGrid
{
    get
    {
        return _isEmptyDataGrid;
    }
    set
    {
        _isEmptyDataGrid = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsEmptyDataGrid");
    }
}
```

---

my problem is that even though the `RaisePropertyChanged("IsEmptyDataGrid")` in my view model is hit, it does not go inside the `IsEmptyDataGrid` property in the custom datagrid and the empty message is displayed along with the data in the source.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks you in advance,
Kruvi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setter of a DependencyProperty is not always called in this scenario. Use a Callback function instead:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEmptyDataGridProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsEmptyDataGrid", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomDataGrid), new UIPropertyMetaData(false,Callback));

private static void Callback(DependecyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CustomDatagrid cdt = d as CustomDatagrid;
    if(cdt._txtEmptyDataGrid != null)
        {
            cdt._txtEmptyDataGrid.Visibility = cdt.IsEmptyDataGrid ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }  
}
```